# React-Native Firebase Snack Expo Failed to resolve dependency

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, package.json

I'm receiving this error in Snack Expo when I try to use firebase:

package.json (7:5)
Failed to resolve dependency 'firebase@9.5.0' (Can't resolve '' in '/tmp/snackager/snackager/buildStatus/1/firebase@9.5.0-ios,android,web/package')

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In package.json file try changing firebase version to "8.0.0".

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "firebase": "8.0.0",
    ...
  }
}
```